# Elasticsearch is not running with error code 128

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm using Elasticsearch 8.6.2 on Ubuntu 22.04. For the past few days, my elastic has not been running. Please help me.

The system output is below:

```
dev@logserver:~$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch
× elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-03-17 09:45:13 CST; 1min 57s ago
       Docs: https://www.elastic.co
    Process: 2133 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=128)
   Main PID: 2133 (code=exited, status=128)
        CPU: 1min 30.382s

Mar 17 09:44:43 logserver systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
Mar 17 09:45:03 logserver systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Mar 17 09:45:13 logserver systemd-entrypoint[2133]: ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly
Mar 17 09:45:13 logserver systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=128/n/a
Mar 17 09:45:13 logserver systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 17 09:45:13 logserver systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 1min 30.382s CPU time.
```

And I have `elasticsearch.log`, but I don't know how can share it.

Please help me

Comment: You can [gist it](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: thank you.
https://gist.github.com/terry1102/afc8c676087ecbe2da9d87c461dd2d1f

Comment: I see two issues: one on line 89 and the one on line 1262 seems more serious as you have a corrupted index

Comment: Maybe it is. What should I do?

Comment: Well a corrupt index is not a trivial thing to fix. Can you run `GET _all?filter_path=**.settings.index.uuid` in Kibana and find the one whose uuid is `JUx2JbIqSxmT1SurkzHf9w` or you don't even get the chance to query your cluster?